# Set Instance level environment variables in Cloud Foundry while scaling application

Tags: spring-boot, rabbitmq, cloud-foundry

I am thinking of way to pass/set environment variable to a cloud foundry instance when we scale it horizontally. The use-case is, we have a producer app using rabbitMQ and a consumer App which is consuming from the queue. We want the consumer app to scale horizontally. For that we are planning to use ["consistent-hash-exchange"](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-consistent-hash-exchange) of rabbitMQ.
The problem is, we are planning to have 3 queue bounded to the 3 consumer instance and we want to pass each queue name to each instance to that there is kind of one-to-one mapping between them.

1) Is there any way in which we can set environment properties at individual instance level ?

2) Is this the right approach?

Thanks in Advance,Sagar

Answer (score 0):

> 1) Is there any way in which we can set environment properties at individual instance level ?

The cf cli will tell you that you need to restage an app for changes to environment variables to take effect. Normally, you can get away with a restart, unless you're changing an env variable that impacts a buildpack/what happens during staging.

I did a quick test and it seems like at least a restart is required. If I change an env variable and scale up my app, all instances have the original env value. After a restart, all instances have the new value. This is probably a good thing, as you don't really want to have different values for different app instances as that could get really confusing.

> 2) Is this the right approach?

Probably not for Cloud Foundry. I would suggest doing something where you have a queue name that's a pattern, like 'somequeue-`. You can then pull the app instance number out of the`VCAP_APPLICATION` environment variable and use that to get a unique queue name per application instance, like 'somequeue-0', 'somequeue-1', and 'somequeue-2'.

Otherwise, you'd need to have the app query the queue name from somewhere like a config server or database. That way it could dynamically load the queue name at start up.

Hope that helps!

Comment: I can try out having the queue names in config server. But again, the problem is, I need to have each individual, to bind to a single queue. But atleast i can give a though in that way. I will let you know how that works.

Comment: For config server see this section on reloading properties, https://docs.pivotal.io/spring-cloud-services/3-0/common/config-server/refreshing-properties.html#refresh-client-app

Comment: I have the config server in place already, but its not that helpful in this scenario. For now what I did, is added 2 manifest.yml and name the application as 01 & 02 and adding the queue name via evn. Its kind of a static scaling way, but lets see how it goes.